# Can any one tell me why weight generated via benchmarking execution is varying on each execution

Tags: substrate-node-template, timestamp

I have written the benchmarking code for the pallet,

Used the below CLI command to run benchmarking -

./target/release/node-template benchmark pallet --pallet pallet_usd_rate --extrinsic "*" --steps=50 --repeat=20 --execution=wasm --wasm-execution=compiled --heap-pages=4098 --output=pallets/usd-rate/src/weights1.rs

But during execution I have seen one surprising thing that on each execution of benchmarking, the calculated weight are different.
It is varying between 10_245_000 to 28_000_000.

I have tried many ways via changing the parameters, but the behaviour is same.
Even I have tried to run the benchmarking of Pallet_timestamp..
But for pallet_timestamp also it is varying, it is not fixed.

I assume it must be fixed value on a particular machine....because there is no change in code..
It should not vary on each execution..

Can anyone explain me the reason for this behaviour.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the code? Then I can try it as well.  
The values are expected to fluctuate, but not that much,

Comment: PS: The benchmarks need to always run on the same hardware. Its best to use the reference hardware https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/maintain-guides-how-to-validate-kusama#hardware

Comment: @OliverTale-Yazdi, 
 Here is code for benchmarking:
https://github.com/asmita-mf/substrate-test/blob/main/pallets/usd-rate/src/benchmarking.rs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I analyzed your benchmark and it looks good, quite consistent (minus one outlier) [µs]:

```
15.76
15.69
15.37
15.55
15.31
31.38
16.07
15.81
15.67
15.43
15.64
15.99
15.44
```

The benchmarks need to be run on the same hardware every time. This is since they measure *time*, and a faster PC scores lower (better) weights.
If you are just doing development you can obviously use any hardware. But before a release it is necessary to re-benchmark the weights on fixed hardware.
A good pick would be the Polkadot [reference hardware](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/maintain-guides-how-to-validate-polkadot#reference-hardware).

Comment: Thank you for you confirmation @OliverTale-Yazdi
I'll re-analyze the benchmarking before going for release on a vm.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, benchmarks have to be run in a stable environment. I've always been getting big variance when running any benchmarks on my PC, because there's a thousand other processes in the background, sharing RAM & CPU with the benchmarks. I think a dedicated (virtual) machine might be a good solution for production benchmarking.